# PHP pthreads: Does Thread::start() ever return FALSE?

Tags: php, pthreads

I was wondering if there are circumstances where [`Thread::start()`](http://php.net/thread.start) returns `false`. The [manual](http://php.net/thread.start) isn't very clear about this.

I was able to let `start()` fail in the following cases. In all cases it throws a [`RuntimeException`](http://php.net/RuntimeException), so no `false` returned.

- **Try to start a thread twice**

  ```
  $thread = new Thread;
  $thread->start();
  $thread->start(); // RuntimeException
  ```
- **Exhaust system resources**

  ```
  class TestThread extends Thread
  {
      public function run()
      {
          sleep(PHP_INT_MAX);
      }
  }
  $threads = [];
  for (;;) {
      $thread = new TestThread;
      if (!$thread->start()) { // RuntimeException eventually
          echo 'FALSE returned.', PHP_EOL; // never printed
          break;
      }
      $threads[] = $thread;
  }
  ```
- **Try to start thread again from thread** *(Note: You can start threads from threads; this is just an example to let it fail.)*

  ```
  class TestThread extends Thread
  {
      public function run()
      {
          // necessary to see the exception
          set_exception_handler(function ($exception) {
              throw $exception;
          });

          self::start(); // RuntimeException
      }
  }
  (new TestThread)->start();
  ```

Comment: Looking at at the C code it appears if you call start with the wrong arguments that can cause it to to return `FAILURE` which I'm guessing gets translated to `FALSE` in php.  You can see the code at the following link: https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads/blob/master/classes/thread.h#L101.  I don't know/use php enough to be able to actually test it.

Comment: Thanks @GabrielSouthern, passing `start()` some unusual argument made it actually return something else than `true`: `null` in this case and an `E_WARNING` is issued. The manual really should be updated.